# ANDROID: Question regarding overlaying a transparent bar to make layout more aesthetic

Tags: android, layout, transparency

How would I go about putting a transparent bar along the top of a scrollview so that when the text scrolls up it kind of fades out towards the top?  I am talking about the kind of thing that the Facebook and NFL mobile apps use.  I think it just makes the whole design look nicer and I was wondering how I could implement this.  Thanks for any suggestions or help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually something that's already built into the `ScrollView`.  Have a look at the `Fading edge` and Fading edge length` properties in the XML.

Comment: Wow didnt even notice that! Thanks!